# The usage of Inhuman

Tags: word-choice

Is it right if I say "how could you act such inhuman?" or "how could you be so inhuman?" Thank you in advance.

Comment: "How could you act **in** such **an** inhuman **way**?"

Comment: See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

*Inhuman* is an adjective, which means we should use *so*, not *such* before it (however, we'd say "such an inhuman person" because *such* can precede nouns and noun phrases):

> How could you be so **inhuman**?

*So* precedes adverbs too, so:

> How could you act so **inhumanly**?